# Deleting files from Google Drive with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, delete-file

I have seen many topics talking about this problem, and I have been struggling with it for a week now: is there a real way to delete/remove/put to trash files from Google Drive using a script?

I have to upload CSV files on Drive to copy some of their rows into a Spreadsheet, and I would like to have these files deleted after use. I used `DriveApp.remove(file.id)`, `Drive.Files.remove(file.id)` and, even though they did nothing on my documents, I did not get any error message...

I can use a method taking filenames, fileIDs in argument, whatever is needed to perform this deletion.

Comment: I'm no expert in this area, but does the apps script have permission to delete files?

Comment: If you aren't the owner, you can't trash it or call `Drive.Files.remove(fileId)` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Apps Script documentation, the [`.removeFile(fileId)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removeFile(File)) method does not delete the file, nor does it trash the file. This method simply removes the file from the current folder.

To delete a file from Google Drive via Apps Script will require using the [`Drive REST API`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) possibly as an [advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). This will skip the "Trash" - it is unrecoverable.

```
function deleteIt(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  if(file.mimeType === MimeType.FOLDER) {
    // possibly ask for confirmation before deleting this folder
  }
  Drive.Files.remove(file.id); // "remove" in Apps Script client library, "delete" elsewhere
}
```

"Trash"ing a file/folder can be done from Google Apps Script without needing to set up and configure the advanced service:

```
function trashIt(fileId) {
  var file;
  try {
    file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  }
  catch (fileE) {
    try {
      file = DriveApp.getFolderById(fileId);
    }
    catch (folderE) {
      throw folderE;
    }
  }
  file.setTrashed(true);
}
```

(Trashing can also be done with the Advanced Service if you need to work with Team Drive items.)

See related questions:
[Permanently delete file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749906/permanently-delete-file-from-google-drive/32749203#32749203)
[Delete or Trash specific file in Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709372/delete-or-trash-specific-file-in-drive)
[Google apps script : How to Delete a File in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241237/google-apps-script-how-to-delete-a-file-in-google-drive)

Comment: Hi tehhowch, thank you very much for your answer! your first proposition worked perfectly. I marked this topic as a duplicate as the other question was speaking about Drive.Files.remove(file.id) too.